# Is it possible to query builds in Azure DevOps REST API using negative filters?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am using the [List Builds API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to query for builds.

I was wondering if it was possible to ask for all the builds with the reason different from `pullRequest`, for example, without actually listing all the other reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to query builds in Azure DevOps REST API using negative
>   filters?

For this issue,it is impossible to use negative filters in azure devops rest api.

The parameters provided in the rest api are defined.There are no such parameters like negative filter in the given parameters. So if we use parameters like `reasonFilter`
, we can only specify the filter values one by one, but not in the form like `exclude`.

To filtering out the builds with the reason different from pullRequest, besides specifying all the required reasons in the `reasonFilter`, you can also filter the return result of the rest api through the code.

For example with powershell script:

```
$url = 'https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{pro}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1';

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"} -Method Get

$results = $response.value | Where {$_.reason -ne "pullRequest"} #|

Write-Host "results = $($results | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"
```

Comment: Post-factum filtering is not a problem. I was specifically wondering if it was possible to filter in the API. I understand it is not. Is it possible to specify regex in the `reasonFilter` or others?

Comment: By trying ,I think it is not feasible to specify like regex in the reasonFilter to filter out the result.